# Export org special text block to Latex

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

My problem is to export this org-block

```
#+BEGIN_NOTE
some text here
#+END_NOTE
```

to this Latex code

```
\begin{bclogo}[logo=\bcattention, noborder=true, barre=none]{some text here}
\end{bclogo}
```

Is there a way to customize how to export in Latex this block of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this with a custom block in org-mode:

## +begin_bclogo

some text here

## +end_bclogo

Then, use a filter to modify the export like this:

```
(defun ox-mrkup-filter-special-block (text back-end info)
  (let ((text (replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\begin{bclogo}" "\\\\begin{bclogo}[logo=\\\\bcattention, noborder=true, barre=none]{" text)))
    (replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\end{bclogo}" "}\\\\end{bclogo}" text)))

(let ((org-export-filter-special-block-functions '(ox-mrkup-filter-special-block)))
(find-file (org-export-to-file 'latex "custom.tex")))
```

That exports to:

```
\begin{bclogo}[logo=\bcattention, noborder=true, barre=none]{
some text here
}\end{bclogo}
```

This seems to get close to what you want. I am not sure how you could get a body in the environment. I think you would need to use an attribute to set the text in {} and then use the text as the body. That is probably not easy to implement in a filter, and would be better implemented in a custom export.

Comment: John thanks for your answer. This script works but I need to mantain the `NOTE` environment, as the document has to be exported in html and Latex. So my question can be better post : is there a way to modify the `#+BEGIN NOTE #+END NOTE` enviroment in a way similar to the `FIGURE` in order to insert a Latex attribute ?

Comment: You can use the back-end variable in the filter to do latex or html specific things in a cond block. What is the html code for export supposed to look like? You may need to consider making a custom exporter though that will build what you want for special blocks, with back-end specific code.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep the `NOTE` environment and replace it with `bclogo` through a latex-specific filter (I modified John's code):

```
(defun my/latex-process-NOTE-blocks (text backend info)
  "Filter special blocks from latex export."
  (when (eq backend 'latex)
    (let ((text (replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\begin{NOTE}" "\\\\begin{bclogo}[logo=\\\\bcattention, noborder=true, barre=none]{" text)))
      (replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\end{NOTE}" "}\\\\end{bclogo}" text))))

(eval-after-load 'ox '(add-to-list
                       'org-export-filter-special-block-functions
                       'my/latex-process-NOTE-blocks))
```

If you want to do this with all latex-derived backends, you can replace `(eq backend 'latex)` with `(org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'latex)`.

If you want to make sure the block starts with `\begin{NOTE}`:

```
(defun string/starts-with (string prefix)
  "Return t if STRING starts with prefix."
  (and (string-match (rx-to-string `(: bos ,prefix) t) string) t))

(defun my/latex-process-NOTE-blocks (text backend info)
  "Filter special blocks from latex export."
  (when (eq backend 'latex)
    (if (string/starts-with text "\\begin{NOTE}")
        (let ((text (replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\begin{NOTE}" "\\\\begin{bclogo}[logo=\\\\bcattention, noborder=true, barre=none]{" text)))
          (replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\end{NOTE}" "}\\\\end{bclogo}" text)))))

(eval-after-load 'ox '(add-to-list
                       'org-export-filter-special-block-functions
                       'my/latex-process-NOTE-blocks))
```

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest to use instead something like:

```
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
...
#+ATTR_LATEX: :options [logo=\bcattention, noborder=true, barre=none]{some title here}
#+BEGIN_bclogo
some text here
#+END_bclogo
```

Using a LaTeX special block is well suited here, unless you really want to use notes.